# TextView after animation resets text size

Tags: android

I want to make text size bigger when I click on TextView and I have code like

/res/anim/scale_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.3"
        android:toYScale="1.3" >

    </scale>

</set>
```

and in code like

```
txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SwipeActivity.this, R.anim.scale_up);
                a.reset();
                v.clearAnimation();
                v.startAnimation(a);
            }
        });
```

and it scales but when it finishes scaling (500ms) it comes back on old size of font. How to prevent that, I want to stay doubled size ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`fillAfter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillAfter) attribute to `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you could set the textsize to the TextView instad of using an animation. Animating it will make the text blurred.

eks:

textView.setTextSize(20);

The reason why the animation pops back to the original size is because you don´t use setFillAfter.

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SwipeActivity.this, R.anim.scale_up);
a.setFillAfter(true);
v.startAnimation(a);
```